# printing diagonals from a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the matrix i need to print a diagonals from:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

i need to print 1, 5, 9 and 3, 5, 7 (separately)

it also should ask for user input for dimensions

this is what i tried to do:

```
n = int(input("enter dimension: "))
lst=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(lst)

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if i == j:
            print(lst[i][j])

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(n-1, 0, -1):
        print(lst[i][j])
```

this halfway works because i do get 1, 5 and 9 but not the 3, 5 and 7.

Comment: Think about the condition the coordinates must fulfill to be on the second diagonal. Write a few coordinates down and think how i and j and n are connected.

Comment: Another consideration: for an `n` by `n` matrix, the diagonal only consists of `n` elements. That should be seen as a hint that you can solve this with only `n` operations, meaning a single `for` loop, instead of the `n^2` operations you perform currently. Consider: do you need to iterate over the possible value of `i` and `j` separately, or can you deduce one from the other?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this for secondary diagonal:(contributed by Mohit Kumar)

```
# Function to print the Secondary Diagonal
def printSecondaryDiagonal(mat, n):
    print("Secondary Diagonal: ", end = "")
 
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
 
            # Condition for secondary diagonal
            if ((i + j) == (n - 1)):
                print(mat[i][j], end = ", ")
    print()
 
# Driver code
n = 4
a = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
     [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
     [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]]

printSecondaryDiagonal(a, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst=[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

diag1 = []
diag2 = []

for col, row in enumerate(lst):
    diag1.append(row[col])
    diag2.append(row[-col-1])
    
print(diag1)
print(diag2)
```

---

*The output:*

> ```
> [1, 5, 9]
> [3, 5, 7]
> ```

---

*The explanation:*

The `enumerate()` function will create from your list something as a list of pairs:

> ```
> [(0, [1, 2, 3]),
>  (1, [4, 5, 6]),
>  (2, [7, 8, 9])]
> ```

The first item of a pair is just the index of the element, which you want to select (I assigned it to the variable `col`):

- element with index `0` from the row `[1, 2, 3]`, i.e. element `1`,
- element with index `1` from the row `[4, 5, 6]`, i.e. element `5`,
- element with index `2` from the row `[7, 8, 9]`, i.e. element `9`.

For the second diagonal you want to select elements counting from the end. For indexing from the end are use negative numbers (`-1` is the last element, `-2` is just the last but one, etc.), i.e. you want to select:

- element with index `-1` from the row `[1, 2, 3]`, i.e. element `3`,
- element with index `-2` from the row `[4, 5, 6]`, i.e. element `5`,
- element with index `-3` from the row `[7, 8, 9]`, i.e. element `7`.

To obtain these indices from the original indices 0, 1, and 2 (sequentially assigned to the variable `col` in the `for` loop), I used the expression `-col-1`:

> ```
> | col | (-col-1) |result|
> |-----+----------+------|
> |  0  |  -0 - 1  |  -1  |
> |  1  |  -1 - 1  |  -2  |
> |  2  |  -2 - 1  |  -3  |
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list comprehensions` to get the 2 diagonals as -

1. As pointed out, since matrix is `mxm` you can simply iterate over the diagonal by iterating over the index range once, as in this case `(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)`
2. For the second diagonal that you require, you can just `reverse` the index range and along with `enumerate` to get the diagonal elements, as in this case `(0,2), (1,1), (2,0)`

Both above methods require iterations of the order `n` only (where n is the length of the diagonal).

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

d1 = [a[i][i] for i in range(len(a))]
d2 = [a[i][j] for i,j in enumerate(reversed(range(len(a))))]

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

```
[1 5 9]
[3 5 7]
```

If you have to print both of these together, you can simply do this by a single iteration over the matrix (order `n`) -

```
d1 = []
d2 = []

for i,j in enumerate(reversed(range(len(a)))):
    d1.append(a[i][i])
    d2.append(a[i][j])
    
print(d1)
print(d2)
```

```
[1 5 9]
[3 5 7]
```

---

If however, you are open to using `NumPy`, you can do this quite easily using `np.diag` as -

```
import numpy as np

d1 = np.array(a).diagonal()
d2 = np.fliplr(a).diagonal()

print(d1)
print(d2)
```

```
[1 5 9]
[3 5 7]
```